# syntax error, unexpected 'Route' (T_STRING)

Tags: laravel, routes, syntax-error

Please Help Me, The Error Says `syntax error, unexpected 'Route' (T_STRING)`, what's wrong with my script ?

Script in Controller:

```
public function tambah(Request $request){
      $tambah = new kategori;
      $tambah->nama_kategori = $request->nama_kategori;
      $tambah->save();
  }
```

Script in Route:

```
localhost:8000/kategori
Route::get('/kategori', function()
{
    return view('kategori');
});
Route::post('/tambahdata', 'KategoriController@tambah')->name('tambahdata');
```

Comment: remove localhost:8000/kategori from route file

Comment: commment this `localhost:8000/kategori` with `//localhost:8000/kategori`

Answer (score 1):

you should remove or comment:

```
localhost:8000/kategori
```

so the route file look like:

```
Route::get('/kategori', function()
{
    return view('kategori');
});
Route::post('/tambahdata', 'KategoriController@tambah')->name('tambahdata');
```